# Video tag in chromecast don't trigger 'waiting' event

Tags: callback, chromecast, receiver

I don't want to use MPL. I want to use myself HTML5 player on chromecast receiver. But when the video tag don't have sufficient buffer to play, it won't trigger 'waiting' event which is ok in Chrome.

Does anyone know why the chromecast don't trigger 'waiting' event?
Or can I choose other method to solve it?

I got below description from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player.

How can I detect the buffering state?

When you are using MPL for adaptive streaming, you should check the MPL state for data underflow instead of checking for waiting/stalled events of the media element. MPL pauses playback to buffer enough media data in the source buffer to resume playback without stutter.

Comment: Does anyone help?

Comment: Does someone can help?